# Calling Personality Insights API from Python server

Tags: python, post, ibm-cloud, personality-insights

I'm trying to call Personality Insights API from my Python web app but it always return the forbidden error 403 but when I call it from Postman Chrome extension it work successfully.

This is my python code:

```
def generatePersonalDescription(request):
    import requests
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
    IBM_API_URL = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v2/profile"
    top_level_url = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api"
    username = "<user>"
    password = "<password>"

    JSON_OBJ = {'contentItems': [{'content' : 'strcontent' , 'contenttype': 'application/json','sourceid': 'blog123','language': 'en'}]}

    json_data = json.dumps(JSON_OBJ)

    resp = requests.get(IBM_API_URL, auth=(username, password))

    return HttpResponse(resp)
```

Is it possible that because the python is a server side and the API isn't allowed to accept requests from server side application?

Comment: Please make sure you do not ever publish your own credentials. They are tied to a paid account, and someone abusing from them might incur on changes to your credit card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. The problem is that i'm using free pythonanywhere account which limit the users form sending requests to external servers to this [whitelist.](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/)
I need to upgrade my account to allow for unrestricted requests.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using HTTP `GET` method, while the [Personality Insights](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/personality-insights/api/v2/#response-handling) profile API accepts `POST`. I am not sure this is the cause of HTTP 403 (it should not), but I would double check your credentials anyway. (By the way, never expose your credentials in a question here -- someone could use/abuse them!).

I would recommend you anyway to use the [Python SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk) where you can abstract from the API requests details. There are examples in the github page for `watson-developer-cloud` linked above. The package is even [available in `pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watson-developer-cloud), so it should be simple to include it from any environment.

Comment: Thank you @herchu I'll check the SDK and get back to you.